# In a NodeJS / Express (& multer) attachment upload utility, how to handle API delete requests?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, multer, delete-file

The below is a rudimentary file upload utility. It handles React / Axios API POSTs satisfactorily. Files get uploaded to the `~uploads` folder under root on the server. How does one add API DELETE handling capability to it? Envision a use case where a user uploads an attachment to a blog post and then deletes the attachment from the blog post. Have had issues locating an example.

```
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer')

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage(
{
    destination: function (req, file, cb)
    {
        cb(null, 'fileuploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb)
    {
        cb(null, file.originalname );
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file')

app.post('/upload',function(req, res)
{
    upload(req, res, function (err) 
    {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError)
        {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        else if (err)
        {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        return res.status(200).send(req.file)
    })
});

app.listen(8001, function() {

    console.log('App running on port 8001');

});
```

EDIT:

Modified `app.delete(...)` to the below, which successfully deletes the file but after about a minute throws this error in the console: `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '<PATH VALUE>']`

```
app.delete('/writer/:file_to_delete', async (req, res) =>
{
    const path = 'assets/uploads/' + req.params.targetFile;

    console.log(path);

    try
    {
        fs.unlink(path)
        // NOTE: `fs.unlinkSync(path)` does the same thing
        console.log('File deleted!');

        return res.status(200);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    }
});
```

Comment: Use the `fs` module to delete the file from the Filesystem and listen for `app.delete` method from a http client.

Comment: @marc, `fs.unlinkSync(path)` succeeded, but then threw `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '<PATH>`. It did some type of double-check. Any clues on how to avoid?

Comment: The file you trying to delete does not exists. post your code!

Comment: Thanks. Code posted in the EDIT above. Please note that it's not that the file doesn't exist initially. There is a file on the disk that successfully gets deleted via that `fs.unsync(...)`. However after a minute it throws that error so it's doing a second pass trying to find the file.

Comment: The issue was that there was no `send()` at the end of the `return res.status(200)`. This works: `return res.status(200).send({data: req.params.file_name + ' deleted'});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way forward. The code is below but I'm happy to hear about better ways to do it:

```
// NOTE: `file_name` values are obfuscated and uniquely generated by the client.
// The actual file name is in data storage.
app.post('/delete/:file_name', (req, res) =>
{
    const theFile = 'attachments/' + req.params.file_name;

    var resultHandler = function(err) { 
        if(err) {
           console.log("file delete failed", err);
           return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        console.log("file deleted");
        return res.status(200).send({data: req.params.file_name + ' deleted'});
    }
    
    fs.unlinkSync(theFile, resultHandler);
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that every one can delete any file in the "attachments" dir if he know the file name.

Comment: In this situation the file names on the hard drive are obfuscated with the true file name only being available in the data store. If there's a better way, I'm open to change.

Comment: Event if they are obfuscated, if i know any valid value i can delete the file. If its critical you should better apply some "user rights" logic to prevent unauthorized deletions, like a db check which user owns which file

Comment: Noted - also proof that the user was logged in too right or is that overkill?

Comment: Without a login i would denie all operation on the API. Regardless what the user is trying. Side note i noticed your comment in the code snippet: "`file_name` values are obfuscated and uniquely generated by the client." -> NEVER EVER!!! Trust a a client, a better way should be to generate a UUID on the server side by the upload part and return this uuid to the client

Comment: I'm wondering if using the database to store the files is better than trying to sync with a file upload server and keep things secure. PostgreSQL supports binary file storage.

Comment: Depends if he use any database. While he use node i assume he also use mongodb. and mongodb has a "gridfs" system which is supposed to store files.

Comment: Postgres? It has the bytea data type.